# What is the difference between layout_alignEnd and layout_alignRight?

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crime Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_title"
        android:text="Crime Date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/crime_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

If i replace `android:layout_alignRight="@id/crime_title"` with `android:layout_alignEnd="@id/crime_title"`, i get the following output:

[image]

The documentation says about [alignEnd](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_alignEnd) :`Makes the end edge of this view match the end edge of the given anchor view ID`, whereas about [alignRight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_alignRight): `Makes the right edge of this view match the right edge of the given anchor view ID`

**Question**: Isn't "a right edge" the same as "an end edge" ? And what does that blue circle, that has appeared, mean ? What is the difference between these two attributes ?

Comment: they both behave the same. In my way, use `layout_alignRight` is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `android:layout_alignRight`  you get a compiler warning saying

> Consider replacing android:layout_alignRight with android:layout_alignEnd="@id/crime_title" to better support right-to-left layouts

If you dont use any right-to-left layouts you won't see any difference between `android:layout_alignRight` and `android:layout_alignEnd`. They behave same.

You can see the difference in preview while editing your layout file by enabling "Preview Right to Left".
When using `android:layout_alignRight` your button will stay always on the right even in right to left layouts:

[image]

When using `android:layout_alignEnd`  your button will be automatically positioned to ensure matching the end edge of the given anchor view ID. This is also what that blue circle means:

[image]